# Is there a site to play Go online against a computer?

Tags: go, online

There are many go servers but all of them seem to be for player-player games. I want to play online against a computer. I found some but it is not an actual go. I was not able to find a real go brain online. Are there any at all?

---

PS: In the end, I registered to KGS and later at WBaduk (but liked KGS much more) and I ended up playing against human players only. I found it much more fun than playing against a computer and since I tried it for the first time (online) I never went back to playing against the computer.

Comment: Related question (for a specific bot): http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-play-darkforest-probably-the-strongest-publicly-avai

Comment: In the end, I registered to KGS and later at WBaduk (but liked KGS much more) and I ended up playing against human players only. I found it much more fun than playing against a computer and since I tried it for the first time (online) I never went back to playing against the computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a game recommendation. While it was on-topic at the time, such questions [are now banned](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/663/3389) and should not be used as a model for future questions.

Comment: @Thunderforge this is a server recommendation, not a game recommendation.

Comment: @Tomas A few days ago, we had a similar question about [playing Diplomacy online](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/32629/3389) that was closed as a recommendation question. I presume that "a server recommendation" means the same as "a website recommendation". Is there some difference here that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I see no reason to close this question, it asks for something very specific and it isn't obvious on which (of the rather few) online Go sites you can also play against some bots.

Comment: thanks @jknappen. Unfortunatelly usefulness is not the first priority of this site. It's the rigid rules that are praised here, which later lead to creating strange sites like [this one](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) which are pulled out of context of any community. I've already given up this fight....

Comment: @jknappen You can vote to reopen this question if you like.

Comment: I've reopened this because, whether or not it's on topic, it's *not* a game recommendation question. It's not a "which game should I buy/play?" poll question, which is what's covered by the game recommendation policy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some Go servers allow computers to "log in" and play just like regular users. On KGS, for example, they are marked with a computer icon, and there is a setting in the "automatch" for finding games with bots. More details are available here: http://www.gokgs.com/help/faq/bots.html

Comment: Aha, nice, I didn't expect to find this on these player-player sites! I was looking for something easier though, here you have to register, find a bot etc... but it will become the last resort if I don't find any other online service.

Comment: @Tomas KGS has guest access.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Cosumi](http://www.cosumi.net/play.html), it plays around 8kyu in my opinion. After the page loads just click on the HTML5 button, don't get scared by the Japanese symbols..

If you browse their page a bit you can even find different modes regarding sizes or rules (for example one color go).

Comment: +1. I believe it's the simplest option (no need to register) and a great one for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

Online-go.com has two bots to play and you don't need an account.
The levels of the bots are 26 kyu and 13 kyu.
Also the bots are always available to play

To challenge a bot:

1. Go to online-go.com click game lobby and chat on the sidebar.
2. Click new game which is located by the bottom left of  the chat box
3. A popup will appear on your screen, click in the top left on the icon of the globe.
4. A dropdown menu will appear click on the option that says computer
5. You can then specify the game settings.
6. Click on Challenge and enjoy!

Comment: Following your instructions, I get a "Authentication credentials were not provided." error.

Comment: @TheThirdMan registering is free. Bots have significantly improved in the past 2 years, the one currently available on OGS plays 1 kyu.

Comment: @Christophe sure, registering is free, but you have to register. I wish there was something like lichess.org that let you play random games without an account against friends online with spectators thanks to the unique URL you can share. There doesn't seem to be anything decent like this for Go.