# What is the easiest way to play DarkForest, probably the strongest publicly available go AI?

Tags: go

The strongest publicly available go AI is probably this: https://github.com/facebookresearch/darkforestGo, since there is currently no way to play AlphaGo.  Is there any way to play this without building it on a local machine?  Is it available on a server somewhere?  Looks like the name on KGS is darkfmcts3 .

Comment: Do you want source?  Stand alone application?  Website?  Do you have a preferred order among those three?  Not to clear what you are wanting.

Comment: I would like easy to run source with good docs on installation and not too many dependencies, standalone, or access through webapp to a server.  Not too picky on how to interact with it just wasn't able to build darkforest from github instructions.

Comment: I looked at the installation docs.  They are very standard for this kind of researchy code.  There are some messages about gcc versioning issues on the boards that you may wish to dig into.  Building from source takes a lot of skill (it shouldn't.  But it does in my experience.)   If you haven't done much programming (and it looks like you haven't from your stack overflow profile) you're going to have problems dealing with source.

Comment: I got it working, I just had to figure out how luarocks worked.  It wasn't that difficult.

Comment: That is most heartening to hear!  Congratulations!

Comment: Define publicly, CrazyStone is publicly available. It need to be bought 80$ but available on computers et mobiles.

Comment: @JonBarker Would you consider self-answering your question with the process that you used? This is likely to be of interest to others.

Comment: github page of DeepForest claims it's KGS 5d. Leela (https://sjeng.org/leela.html), while not open-source, is available for free and seems to be KGS 8d. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Hactar go https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.gowrite.hactarLite (android application) offers darkforest as opponent (darkforest running on server side). Not free, but 2€/3 month subscription.

Answer (score 1):

(Edit: my answer is incorrect since these bots seem to have been taken offline).

There are a number of bots on kgs that run DarKForest that you can play against.

These are its accounts:

darkfmcts3

darkfmcts2

darkfmcts1

darkfores2

darkfores1

darkforest

Playing against this bot on KGS is probably the easiest way for most people to play against it.

Comment: Are these always online?  I have not seen them online the few times I have logged on.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that they have all been taken offline.  Perhaps the creator will put out a new version of the bot.

Comment: Anyone could in theory rebuild the bot and deploy a bot to the KGS servers though correct?