# Where can I play diplomacy online?

Tags: diplomacy

I'm wanting to start an in-office game of diplomacy - the requirements are:

- Can restrict game to one turn per day.
- If people don't make a move (they are a way), some default action is taken.
- Moves are not required on the weekend.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the question can be answered on this site. Game recommendation questions [are banned](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/663/3389), and by extension, computerized game recommendations too.

Comment: sure this question could be answered on this site. all the major sites should work, you could set up a private game on dpjudge, webdiplomacy, backstabbr, playdiplomacy, ... (by "should", I haven't personally tested them all, but I'd be surprised if any don't offer this functionality)

Comment: There is an Android app called Droidippy that I've been using for some now. It offers all the functionality that you list here, other than "moves are not required on a weekend".