# Is there a site to play Go online against a computer, in 2018?

Tags: go, online, computer-ai

Apparently there's an old question [Is there a site to play Go online against a computer?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18542/is-there-a-site-to-play-go-online-against-a-computer) already but that's in 2014.

As we know AlphaGo/Master/Zero permanently changed the Go world, and many AI are competing the “2nd strongest” after AlphaZero retired. Is there a site to play Go online against one or (nowadays) more computers?

Comment: If it suffices to be able to play against a top bot offline, i.e. in your own machine, then there is e.g. the Lizzie interface for Leela Zero

Comment: You can play Leela Zero and Kata Go online at https://www.zbaduk.com The website also offers great tools to review your games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/18549/3648) in your [linked question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18542/3648) is still valid: ELF (the Facebook go bot, account name "ELF") or variants of LeelaZero play on the [Kiseido Go Server](https://gokgs.com/) (usually bots have "LeelaZero" or "LZ" in their names). You can find a list of these bots in the room "Computer Go" (Menu "Rooms" > Room List > Social > Computer Go)

Comment: Should vote to close this question as a duplicate of the other question since it was answered there or flag it if you don't have the vote to close privilege. .